# Persisting the localstorage values into redux form fields using initialValues attribute

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, reactjs-flux, redux-form, redux-framework

I've a requirement to persist the redux form fields even after page reloads. 
So my approach for this is

- First before page refreshes all field values from my component will be saved to localstorage in componentDidUpdate method

  `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  prevProps.fields ? localStorage.setItem('fields', JSON.stringify(prevProps.fields)):null
  prevProps.fields ? localStorage.setItem('fields', JSON.stringify(prevProps.fields)):null 
  }`
- Then after page refreshes, I'm checking if there are any fields are available in localstorage then I'm assigning those fields object directly to my reduxform initial values

`let reduxFormFunc = reduxForm(
      {
        form: 'rentSelection',
        destroyOnUnmount: false,
        fields: guestEntryFields,
        validate,
        initialValues: getInitFields()
      },
      selectProps
    )
    function getInitFields() {
      let initValues = {pgu: defaultpgu}
        if(localStorage.getItem('fields') && JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fields')).listings.length>0){
          console.log('selecting and assigning fields from localstorage')
          let fields = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fields'))
          console.log(fields)
          initValues['commonFields'] = fields.commonFields
          initValues['listings'] = fields.listings
          initValues['pgu'] = fields.pgu
        }
        console.log(initValues)
      return initValues
    }
export default reduxFormFunc(GuestEntry)`

Now I can access "listings", "pgu", "commonFields" values in my GuestEntry react component. and listings object contains nested level of objects. While iterating and accessing it, all its "value" attribute String values of nested objects inside listings object are converted into object

From this discussion
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/576
I got to know that we have to call the value property on value attribute, something like this

```
listings[0].entry.value.value
```

here value is a string, but as its converted into object I need to call value.value.

So any quick solution to fix this issue?
Or is it fixed in latest version of redux-form? I'm currently using 
"redux-form": "^4.2.0",

Comment: I use `redux-persist` and everything in my stores are rehydrated (unless I've blacklisted a specific key) when the page reloads.

Comment: redux-persist works perfectly for this.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any alternate way in this version, So I just updated the code in such a way that, If I get the value as a instance of object then I'm responding back with the value using "object.value", else I'm just simply returning the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is best practice but I'm simple using `redux-localstorage` to persist the `redux-form` `values` field to localstorage. This means that the form state object will remain as is in terms of validation rules and registered fields etc, but the values will persist (this is important because I don't want the validation to tell me that fields are invalid before they've been touched).

I wrote a custom `slicer` in the `config` object of `redux-localstorage` so that it knows which part of the form state to persist. Here's what my `store.js` file looks like as an example (I'm using `redux-thunk` in this particular application which you might not):

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import persistState from 'redux-localstorage';
import rootReducer from './reducers/root';

const enhancer = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  persistState(['someOtherStateKey', 'form'], {
    slicer: paths => state => {
      let persist = {};
      paths.forEach(path => {
        switch (path) {
          case 'form':
            persist[path] = {
              myFormName: {
                values: state[path].myFormName.values,
              },
            };
            break;
          default:
            persist[path] = state[path];
        }
      });
      return persist;
    },
  })
);

function configureStore() {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
      window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    enhancer
  );
}

const store = configureStore(); // I instantiate here so I can `import` in utils files
export default store;
```

My `Form.js` would have the following code in it:

```
Form = reduxForm({
  form: 'myFormName',
})(Form);
```

You don't need to worry about manually updating or retrieving from localstorage in this example, and you don't need component mount or unmount listeners.

See the `redux-localstorage` `config.slicer` [docs](https://github.com/elgerlambert/redux-localstorage#configslicer) for more information.

**EDIT:** I've decided to go with setting the `initialValues` after all as I wanted to combine a method of having default values in the form as well as persisting the form data. In my previous solution I noticed that using `initialValues` alongside persisting the `redux-form` `values` would cause issues. However, copying the form data to a separate key in the store, as well as using `initialValues` seemed to do the trick.

To do this, I'm setting the `initialValues` during initialisation of Redux Form to a combination of my default form state (held in the redux store) and the persisted form values (which are also held in store). I'm also making use of the `onChange` handler to execute my action creator, which stores the form values in a separate section of the store, and `redux-localstorage` persists this. Code as follows:

```
// initialState.js
export default {
  values: {}
  initialValues: {
    agreeToTerms: false,
  },
};

// Form.js
Form = connect(state => ({
  initialValues: {
    ...state.initialValues, // our defaults
    ...state.values, // our persisted values
  },
  onChange: (values, dispatch, props) => {
    props.myReduxActionFile.updateValues(values);
  },
}))(Form);

// myReduxActionFile.js
...code to dispatch action to update store.values

// store.js
const enhancer = compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk),
  persistState('values')
);
```